# Are these data points decaying exponentially or as a power law?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, dataset, exponential-distribution, power-law, mathematica

0

I have a set of data points. The first coordinate is time and the second coordinate is energy. I am trying to figure out how the energy is decaying over time. Particularly, I have to find if it is decaying over time exponentially or as a power law. I used Mathematica FindFit to model my points as both an exponential decay and a power law decay. It turned out that the exponential decay describes my data points better. But I am not sure if I am doing the right thing. I also plotted my data points in a ListLogPlot and ListLogLogPlot. In both cases, I got a straight line. So, I am a little confused about the actual behavior of my data points. Could anyone help me with this issue? I am copying my data points here. Note that I am only interested in the late-time behavior of the function, not the entire time axis. Thank you!

Data1={{5,0.0210796},{7,0.0293022},{9,0.0302858},{11,0.0257149},{13,0.0182589},{15,0.0106745},{17,0.00473577},{19,0.00101295},{21,-0.000754187},{23,-0.00117344},{25,-0.000860244},{27,-0.000278088},{29,0.000293337},{31,0.00072545},{33,0.000988823},{35,0.00110603},{37,0.00111822},{39,0.00106582},{41,0.000980234},{43,0.000882181},{45,0.000783367},{47,0.000689278},{49,0.0006018},{51,0.000521108},{53,0.000446822},{55,0.000378596},{57,0.000316303}, {59, 0.000259989190761133}}

Comment: what counts as late time? If you have a specific time, why give data before then?

Comment: @Glen_b What I meant by late time is the times after like 35. I just provided the entire data in case someone wants to see the entire plot. There wasn't any particular reason.

Comment: The problem with choosing 35 is that there's a mode (a local maximum) around time 38, so that *can't* be where you count "late" and be debating between two monotonic functions; the relationship is not monotonic there. It looks to me like your first step should be to actually *look* at the data. If you're just going to choose it arbitrarily like that, at least take t>40 so it's monotonic. In that case I suggest comparing a plot of log(y) vs t with a plot of sqrt(y) vs t. You may find that captures most of the relevant issues.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like using the `MASS::boxcox` function in R suggests the same conclusion. However, I'd strongly suggest reviewing some of the answers that mention the [blog post](http://bactra.org/weblog/491.html) by Shalizi and the [paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/070710111) by Clauset, Shalizi and Newman in relation to power laws (arxiv version here: https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.1062), as well as reading those two links directly.

Comment: I should clarify, though. While Shalizi (and the paper) are mostly discussing power-law distributions rather than power law relationships between two variables (which would impact things like suitable analyses, displays etc), some of the cautionary comments are still pretty relevant.

Comment: Exponential decay means on a log-linear plot the right tail of the points looks linear.  It's not -- it decays a little faster than linearly -- but you can still approximate the tail with a linear function.  Its slope depends on how many points you take.  Somewhere between 2 and 11 will work.  *Draw the plot* and use your judgment.

Comment: @HadamardN2 Illustration relating to my comments: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wnwf9.png

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: However, be very careful of extrapolation beyond where you have data.